# Deleting a SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I used this reference to copy over a database I have:

[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

But when the database is copied over and I remove the database file from my assets folder and run my app it still reads the database.  So what I have been doing is renaming the db file and running it again for testing purposes.  I don't like this cause I feel its taking up unnecessary space.  But I was wondering if I can somehow delete the database that was copied over so I wont have to keep renaming.  Anyone know?

Comment: Add a versioning schema so you know that you've put a new database version and check the version in `checkDataBase` in addition to existance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-existing-database-with-android-app/9109728#9109728

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will not be able to delete it, but in this way you can generate a new one with changing the version :

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // Increase ==> new empty DB created

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
}
```

In your code the version is 1, you can increase it and generate a new empty database.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the database in your assets folder, but don't forget to change the name in your DbHelper as well!